# Bevel doesn't offset

Tags: bevel, axis

I'm new to learning Blender and being in the process of learning to understand lights, I wanted to make a studio light but in wanting to bevel the side of my plane to make a curve, the bevel only applies to one axis and doesn't "offset".

On the screenshots I just added a plane, scaled it, extruded one edge, selected the edge and ctrl+B to bevel, but it always do the same result, if not the same but on the Z axis, like the angle seems to contain 2 different edges who are not merged together and, by only doing an extrusion, I don't get why.

Sorry if my question is frequently asked but I didn't find any response, maybe my formulation is bad or I'm not doing my researches with the right terms :(

Thank you !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the scale of your object in Object mode? (Ctrl A)

Comment: Yes, I've already read this on other topics but nothing changes :(

Comment: I think you have duplicate vertices there. In edit mode and vertex select mode, select everything with A and go to Mesh > Merge > By distance

Comment: if it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much Gorgious, I don't know why I had duplicate vertices though